# Network-related error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

the following error appears when I want to launch the Security tab in ASP .NET Configuration site for my ASP NET MVC 4 project:

http://s14.postimg.org/jvizqragv/error_sql.png

I know that there are a lot of questions related to that error, but i tried a lot of the tips for solving this (I tried the suggested solutions here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx but the error is still here).

But let me explain what are my databases in the solution. I have a local database (an .MDF file in App_Data) and a database for users authentication which was generated by ASP NET MVC. They are all placed in the App_Data folder as I'm trying to work on this solution on different machines. The strange thing is that on my laptop at home there is no such problem - I am able to create roles, explore users and all the functionality in the Security tab and I think there might be some problem with the SQL Server on my desktop machine - I use the Express edition on my laptop and the Developer edition on the other machine where things don't work.

My connection strings are the following:

```
<add name="FootballTransfers20130717145140Context" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\FootballTransfers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DefaultConnection.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The first one is for the Entity framework and is related to the database where I store my application specific data. The second one is for the users administration database generated by SQL. Without the second connection string I'm not able to open any action of the Account controller.

It's very strange because it works on one machine and not on another. I was wondering if there's something wrong with the connection string, but I guess there's something with the SQL Server. As I said I tried various solutions but they didn't work.

Comment: While you are using Entity framework ,your connection string automatically generated and for EF provider will be  "System.Data.EntityClient". your DB location doesn't matter whether is app_data or on server.EF will take corrective action.

Answer (score 0):

LocalDB is a feature of SQL Server Express only. You will have to install SQL Server Express on the machine or import your database to your SQL Server and change your connection strings.

In production, you would probably have to move to a full SQL Server edition anyway.

Comment: Actually the other database's connection string uses LocalDb for accessing a local .mdf file and it works. What's the reason it won't work for the users?

Comment: @Niks probalby explained it. EF fixed the first connection string while ASP.NET tried to connect directly using the second string and failed. Still, the message is unambiguous- you are trying to connecto to a non-existent SQL Server instance

Comment: I posted a new reply, it was too long to post here.

Answer (score 0):

I added the roles i was trying to make in code in the AccountController and now I'm able to register users with roles, but the problem that appeared now is that when I put the Authorize attribute on some action so that only users with certain roles can request them, the following error appears:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

When I remove the attribute so anyone can access it, the action works fine. I found some article on the net saying that providers must be specified in the config, but some errors kept appearing that those tags are unknown.

Comment: Authorize calls down to the database. I suppose by "adding the roles" you modified the database using a different connection string? So when you tried to use the connection string that failed before, it failed again? Please add your database to SQL Server and fix the connection string